# Set Custom Error messages per rule for Form Validation - Bonfire

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

I am having trouble setting my custom Error Messages upon Form Validations for every Rule.

I have tried it from Bonfire documentation [here](http://ci3docs.cibonfire.com/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-rules-using-an-array)

Here is some code of my Model of a Module

```
class Content_management_system_model extends BF_Model {

    protected $table_name = 'article';
    protected $key = 'id';

    // be updating a portion of the data.
    protected $validation_rules = array(
         array(
            'field' => 'article_alias',
            'label' => 'lang:content_management_system_article_alias',
            'rules' => 'unique[article.article_alias,article.id]',
            'errors' => array(
                'unique' => 'This is my custom error',
            ),
        ),
```

And here the rules are being set from Admin Controller when Inserting

```
private function save_content_management_system($type = 'insert', $id = 0) {

        // Validate the data
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->content_management_system_model->get_validation_rules());
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === false) {
            return false;
        }
```

But it always shows default message `The value in "Article Alias" is already being used.`

As per documentation in mentioned link, it should show error `This is my custom error`

Answer (score 1):

use callback function:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('current_pswd', 'Current Password', 'trim|required|callback_alias_exist_check');


public function alias_exist_check($str)
            {
>>Put your code here
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed at the end of your $validation_rules array, it is ended by a comma (,) instead of a semicolon (;). Please also remove the comma for the nested array since there are no other arrays after your first nested array.

**Remove the comma(,) and replaced with a semicolon (;)**

```
protected $validation_rules = array(
         array(
            'field' => 'article_alias',
            'label' => 'lang:content_management_system_article_alias',
            'rules' => 'unique[article.article_alias,article.id]',
            'errors' => array(
                'unique' => 'This is my custom error',
            )
        );
```

Also, your

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() **===** false) {
            return false;
        }
```

have a 3 'equal to' operator, which is unnecessary. Make it to only 2 'equal to' operator.

**Another suggestion:**

Since you are calling the **content_management_system_model**'s function **get_validation_rules** why not create a function **get_validation_rules()** and create an array inside the function and then return the array instead of assigning the array to a protected variable?

```
function get_validation_rules()
{
    $validation_rules = array(
         'field'  => 'article_alias',
         'label'  => 'lang:content_management_system_article_alias',
         'rules'  => array(
              'unique'   => 'This is my custom error',
          )   
    );
    return $validation_rules;
}
```

Let me know if you have further questions and if the error still persists. Cheers!

Comment: ` it is ended by a comma (,)` Nahh ... that would have given me error

I just skipped some code there to not to post on SO .... otherwise my array is fine

Comment: Have you tried creating a function **get_validation_rules**?